# How to count a unique customer name given it is (1) recorded in two rows and (2) has different addresses?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

**Scenario:**

Suppose CName represents the customer names. Consider John Smith. His new address is the same regardless of how the old address was inputted (even if they were different old addresses). This also occurs with Sandra Zay.

Now, consider Joe Piper's old address vs new address. His old addresses are respectively the same as the new addresses. This also occurs with Jane Tolar.

```
+------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
|    CName         |     Old_Address        |     New_Address   |
+------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
|  John Smith      |  123 Nowheresville     | 123 Nowheresville |
|  John Smith      |  456 Evergreen Terrace | 123 Nowheresville |
|  Sandra Zay      |  155 Rombust Ave       | 155 Rombust Ave   |
|  Sandra Zay      |  276 Alternews St      | 155 Rombust Ave   |
|  Joe Pipers      |  999 Somewhereelse     | 999 Somewhereelse |
|  Joe Pipers      |  876 BeautifulPl       | 876 BeautifulPl   |
|  Jane Tolar      |  145 Someplace         | 145 Someplace     |
|  Jane Tolar      |  732 Happyland         | 732 Happyland     |
+------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

**Approach:** I have a dataset that is analogous to this in Impala (using Hive SQL). I am interested in counting how many records are inputted just like Joe Pipers and Jane Tolar. That is, step by step, I want Hive SQL to find these two records:

```
|  Joe Pipers    |  999 Somewhereelse     | 999 Somewhereelse |
|  Joe Pipers    |  876 BeautifulPl       | 876 BeautifulPl   |
```

and count this as 1 CName row, and then find these records:

```
|  Jane Tolar      |  145 Someplace         | 145 Someplace     |
|  Jane Tolar      |  732 Happyland         | 732 Happyland     |
```

and also count this as 1 CName row.

**Output:**

```
+-----------------+
|  count(CNames)  |
+-----------------+
|       2         |
+-----------------+
```

Any help or clarification would be great!

Comment: Maybe I'm just unfamiliar with Hive SQL, but if it is a primary key, in my experience that tends to mean that it is also a unique index, and thus there shouldn't be _any_ duplicate entries for that column.

Comment: Yeah I have to change the wording of my question. It sounded confusing.

Comment: I think I see what you're asking now, you want to find the rows where `Old_Address = New_Address`? If so, I've basically said the plain-english version of what you need in the last sentence. You might also put a constraint on the table that `Old_Address != New_Address` to avoid these entries.

Comment: Not necessarily. If so, then it would be easy to put `WHERE Old_Address = New_Address` and do a `COUNT(CName)`. However, that would output a count of 2 (only for Joe Pipers).

I am interested in having the output be 1 because there is only 1 customer that had two records where the old and new addresses are the same (for each row), but the addresses are overall different. Does that make more sense?

Comment: `Count(Distinct CNAME)`  but I don't understand the question yet.  But I see how to solve the question in the comment.. :P

Comment: "Only 1 customer that had two records where the old and new addresses are the same" and expected input/output is some pretty critical question info. Provide some more examples of what should and should not be considered in the final result.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Sorry folks, I will provide more information. Thank you all for trying to help thus far!

Comment: Okay, I gave more information if this helps.

Comment: So your rules are: a CNAME must have the same old/new address more than once to be counted; and then only counted once?  I say more than once because John Smith has the same value once; but not twice.  and you don't' appear to care about that one.  We also don't know if there could be the same cname 40 times and 22 of them could be "the same" in which case you'd expect to count only once as well...  We also don't know if you have duplicates in the data which ould return false positives.  SO we may have to distinct the set to begin with?  Stupid data why isn't it easy!?!?! :P

Comment: Put another way:  WHat is the question about this data you're trying to answer?   a unique count of CNAMES which only have the same new/old address? A unique count of users having more than 1 "New" Address?  Something else?

Comment: The question is that I want to count the unique number of CNames which have the same old/new addresses.

Answer (score 0):

So if the question you're trying to answer is: "I need a count of distinct cnames where the old/new address match for every occurrence of a CNAME"... this should work...   if that's not the question: then define it in common English as I just don't get it yet.

Maybe:

- Get a list of all cnames which old and new address do not match (this is our exclusion list)
- eliminate those from the base table (not exists)
- count Distinct those CNAMES which remain  (this would be those cnames who ONLY have matching old/new addresses on all records regardless of #. if just 1 cname entry has a different old/new address, it would be excluded that CNAME from the count)

.

```
SELECT count(Distinct A.cname)
FROM TableName A
WHERE A.CNAME not exists (SELECT 1 
                          FROM TableName B 
                          WHERE B.Old_Adddress <> B.New_Address
                            AND B.Cname = A.CName)
```

This could be done as a set operation as well

- SET 1 get list of cnames which have old/new address not matching
- get list of all records
- MINUS
- get list of all records EXCEPT those having a cname in set 1